# How to use / pass parameters to event handlers?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, parameters

I already found some information about this topic, but I still don't fully understand it and would be happy if someone would show me how to do it on my example.

Basically, I've got an array filled with objects in VB.Net Windows Forms Application

```
Dim button(9) As cbuttons

public sub fill()
   button(1) = New cbuttons("buttonName1", 2, true)
   button(2) = New cbuttons("ButtonName2", 3, true)
   button(3) = New cbuttons("ButtonName3", 4, true)
   ...
```

This array serves as a source for buttons, which are dynamically generated

```
public sub writeButtons()
    For Each item As cbutton In button

        Dim cmbDynamic As New Button()
        cmbDynamic.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(item.getX(), item.getY())
        cmbDynamic.Name = item.getname()
        cmbDynamic.Text = item.getName() & vbCrLf & item.getTypeString()
        TabPage1.Controls.Add(cmbDynamic)
        AddHandler cmbDynamic.Click, AddressOf Me.clicked 'here is the problem
```

Then I've got a sub that should do something like this

```
public sub clicked()
  MessageBox.Show("You clicked on button " & ButtonName)
```

However, I have no idea how to pass the button name (nor any other parameters) to the sub *clicked()*, because I can't add any parameter to the *AddHalnder* line and *callByName()* also doesn't work

I'm looking for a solution that could look like this in Javascript:

```
  onlick="clicked(this.id)"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method must have parameters matching the `Control.Click` event delegate, which in this case is `EventHandler`. Therefore, `clicked` method needs an `Object` type parameter followed by `EventArgs` type parameter.

The first parameter represents the object for which the event occured. Therefore, upon casting it within the handler you will be able to get any of its properties, including `Name`:

```
Public Sub clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked on button " & CType(sender, Control).Name)
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

In the comments, you ask if it's possible to pass extra parameters to event handler methods. To that, the short answer is that you shouldn't rely on that possibility - especially for events defined outside your codebase.

> **NOTE**: For your own, self-defined events, this is easy: you do your own `EventArgs`-derived type and put whatever you want in there.

There are ways around this, though. You could store values within class scope and access them in the handler. You could create a dictionary of values whose keys would be something that uniquely identifies your buttons.

A less elegant method would be to store information in each `Button`'s `Tag` property. Since the handler always have an `Object` parameter representing the object raising the event, you can retrieve any of its properties within its context.

For example, when you create a new `Button` instance, you can set its `Tag` property to the `cbutton` value from which it is being created:

```
Public Sub writeButtons()
    ' ...

    Dim cmbDynamic As New Button()
    ' ...
    cmbDynamic.Tag = item

    ' ...
End Sub
```

So, later on, you'll be able to recover the full `cbutton` value simply by doing this:

```
Public Sub clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim item As cbutton = btn.Tag

    MessageBox.Show("You clicked on button " & item.getname() & " which has cbutton.anyproperty equals to " & item.anyproperty)

    
End Sub
```

You can think of `Tag` property as freestyle storage.

Word of advise though: *do not abuse of it*. The more you use it, the harder your code will be to figure out. Plus, you might end up having unexpected values in these should you have more than one mechanic that uses them.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:**

As per .NET conventions, the preferred casing for types and type members is for every words to start with a capital letter. For example, `writeButtons` really should be `WriteButtons`. I should also mention that methods starting with `Write` suggests I/O operations happening. In your case, `CreateButtons` sounds more appropriate.

Comment: You really helped me a lot, thanks. Even thought I don't need it right now, I'm curious if it is possible to pass more than 1 parameter like this.