# VB.NET Event Handler as the producer of a multithreaded producer-consumer pattern

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, event-handling, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

The pattern below smells for a few reasons, but for the purposes of this question, let's focus on the global variables and the event handler:

```
Dim objectQueue As New BlockingCollection(Of Object)
Dim objectQueueCancel As New CancellationTokenSource

Sub Main()
    Task.Run(Sub()
                 If Console.ReadKey.KeyChar() = "c" Then objectQueueCancel.Cancel()
             End Sub)
    Dim t1 As Task = Task.Run(Sub() NonBlockingConsumer())
    Dim t2 As Task = Task.Run(Sub() NonBlockingProducer())
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2)
    objectQueueCancel.Dispose()
    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit.")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub NonBlockingProducer()
    Dim sourceObjects As ICollection(Of Object) = Nothing 'Sanitized for StackOverflow
    For Each sourceObject In sourceObjects
        If sourceObject.IsEnabled Then
            Dim objectEventGenerator As New objectEventGenerator(sourceObject)
            AddHandler objectEventGenerator.objectEvent, AddressOf Handler_ObjectEvent
            objectEventGenerator.Enabled = True
        End If
        If objectQueue.IsAddingCompleted Then Exit For
    Next sourceObject
End Sub

Public Sub Handler_ObjectEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As objectEventArgs)
    If Not objectQueue.IsAddingCompleted Then
        If Not e.EventException Is Nothing Then
            Environment.ExitCode = -1
        Else
            Dim itemToAdd As Object = Nothing
            Dim itemQueued As Boolean = False
            Do
                Try
                    itemQueued = objectQueue.TryAdd(itemToAdd, 0, objectQueueCancel.Token) 'TODO Tweak enqueue timeout
                Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
                    objectQueue.CompleteAdding()
                    Exit Do
                End Try
                If itemQueued Then
                    itemToAdd = Nothing
                Else
                    Thread.Sleep(0)
                End If
            Loop While Not itemQueued
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The only way of programmatically accessing the objects in the target use case is through an event listener, and while this code executes it has two pesky global variables. If I define / Dim the BlockingCollection and CancellationTokenSource in the Main() sub, I would have to pass them (I expect ByRef) into the event handler by way of NonBlockingProducer(). However, the event handler's signature is fixed, i.e. I can't simply extend it to be able to pass the variables in...

What is the "proper" way of refactoring this to eliminate the global variables?

Comment: Through `objectEventArgs`?

Comment: As I understand it, objectEventArgs is defined and passed to the handler by the event generator / calling method from the external class; I don't believe there is a way to append my own parameters into it.

Comment: I guess it depends whether you have source code access to `objectEventArgs`. Is this a subclass of the standard `EventArgs` class? Many classes that raise events create a subclass of `EventArgs` to hand event parameters to the handler.

Comment: It is indeed a subclass of EventArgs, but one that I do not have access to the source for it.

Comment: Conventional wisdom as to whether this is possible per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139473/how-to-use-pass-parameters-to-event-handlers is no. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Hmm. Where do you want `objectQueue` and `objectQueueCancel` to live? As local variables in `main`? Or elsewhere?

Comment: I'd like to declare them in main, as I have been told by people wiser than me that global variables are A Bad Thing.

Comment: In that case they will need to be passed into `NonBlockingProducer` and `NonBlockingConsumer`, then added as a property of `objectEventGenerator`. You can then `DirectCast` the `sender` parameter in the event handler to retrieve the property. If you do not have source code access to `objectEventGenerator` then I doubt you will be able to remove the global variables.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend shim the event to append to objectEventArgs without directly extending or inheriting from objectEventGenerator?